# как добавить в cmake -pthread?

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, сборка

Есть cmake файл, как добавить в него посикс потоки -pthread и библиотеку буста(установлен в системе) на примере boost.thread?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
```

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ссылка на родственный проект](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)

Если CMake свежий (3.1+), тогда так

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

Если лень что то писать и разбираться, заработает где то так, но это для линукса

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "... -lpthread")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "... -lpthread")
```

но это если совсем лень.